# How to show the only date in react-datetime-picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using the react-datetime-picker npm module for selecting date.I need to display the date only without time

```js
import DatePicker from 'react-datetime-picker';
  
 onChange(date){
  this.setState({
   profileSetting:{dob:date}
   });
  }

  <DatePicker className="form-control"
  disableClock={true}
  locale="en-US"
  onChange={this.onChange}
  value={this.state.profileSetting.dob}
  />
```

present date displayed like "10/20/2018 12:00 AM" but i need to display date like "10/20/2018".Please help me out of this issue

Comment: Why not use input type date? 
`<input type="date">`

Comment: https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker
u can try this instead

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-moment ?

Answer (score 2):

In on `onChange` method, you can simply format your date as per your requirement

```
const selectedDate = new Date('10/20/2018 12:00 AM'); // pass in date param here
const formattedDate = `${selectedDate.getMonth()+1}/${selectedDate.getDate()}/${selectedDate.getFullYear()}`;
console.log(formattedDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use bootstrap input and put type = "text"

```
**<input type="date" />**
```

If you use this u don't need another library and use instead react hook forms which will handle controlled components in your forms

Comment: His question is about the, react-datetime-picker library, and you're going out of context.